# Converting collection of binary data in dictionary of occurencies with python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, str-replace, series

I have some data in CSV format which looks like:

```
Time [s],Data
0.000916000000000,0b  1111  1110  0100  0100  0000  1111  0011  1100
0.024800000000000,0b  1111  1110  0100  0100  0000  1111  0011  1100
0.048684000000000,0b  1111  1110  0100  0100  0000  1111  0011  1100
...
4.729276000000000,0b  1111  1110  0100  1000  0000  1111  0000  1100
```

I would like to know which binary codes occures and how often to be sure which are the significant signals.

I realized this could be easily achieved with python pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
csv_data = pd.read_csv('./captures/idle binary.csv')
occurencies = csv_data['Data'].value_counts()
```

This gives me this output:

```
0b  1111  1110  0100  0100  0000  1111  0011  1100    195
0b  1111  1110  0100  0000  0000  1111  0010  1100      8
0b  1111  1110  0100  1000  0000  1111  0000  1100      6
Name: Data, dtype: int64
```

First, I woould like to remove the 0b and all the whitespaces from the data to get

```
11111110010001000000111100111100
```

and I would like to transpose the data so I have the number of occurencies as indexes

```
195   11111110010001000000111100111100 
  8   11111110010000000000111100101100
  6   11111110010010000000111100001100
```

For the first goal I tried to use

```
occurencies.replace('0b', '')
```

for the second one I tried

```
occurencies.transpose()
```

but this did not work. I could easily do

```
occurencies.to_dict()
```

and than swicht the dict keys and values and edit the values, but I would like to achieve the same with pandas.

Comment: IIUC then the following should work: `occurencies.str.replace('0b','').str.replace(' ','')` to concatenate the str, to achieve your next bit you need to swap the data and index around, I'd just construct a new Series with the data swapped around, `s = pd.Series(index = occurencies.values, data = occurencies.index)`

Comment: I already tried str.replace but I get following error:

raise AttributeError("Can only use .str accessor with string "
AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas

Answer (score 0):

Usually you want your index to represent a unique value which could easily be violated if you use the results of `value_counts` as the index.

To strip your string and rearrange your columns:

```
df = csv_data['Data'].value_counts().reset_index()
df.columns = ['byte', 'count']
df['stripped_bytes'] = df.byte.str.split().apply(lambda x: "".join(x[1:]) if len(x) else "")
df[['count', 'stripped_bytes']]
   count                    stripped_bytes
0    195  11111110010001000000111100111100
1      8  11111110010000000000111100101100
2      6  11111110010010000000111100001100
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explaining code. It helped a lot, I was finnaly able to use the str. replace() function to strip all the whitespaces and the 0b at the beginning.